# Issue with auto.arima adding .xreg to term names

Tags: r, arima

I have run around 90 time series auto.arima models with success, however for 2 models my terms have been renamed with a xreg. added to the title, and this is messing with my loop.

From what I can see, this has been added when a drift coefficient has been added to the model outputs (my other models have AR or MA coefficients)

```
 Names in time series:
 Volume
 Price.Diff
 School
 Easter

 Names in model outputs:
 xreg.Price.Diff
 xreg.School
 xreg.Easter
```

Should I simply clean these manually?

#### Temporary Fix

```
  for(i in 1:length(z$term)){
  z$term<-gsub(z$term, pattern = 'xreg.',replacement = "")

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

This was occurring when model used a drift term and exogenous regressors.

Bug fixed, see https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues/792